# Json_decode not functioning expecting array to be a string

Tags: php, json, rest, api

Hello all im working with an API. From this In this API there's a lot of data. I'm trying to get a specific bit. Like this:

```
$SimplicateApi = new SimplicateApi('emark.domain.nl','key','secret');
$json = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/crm/person?q[first_name]=Kevin');
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

I wanted to print the data decoded from the API.
I just want to print it on my web page to see if its working any other methods are okay with me too. as long i can see the data on my webpage.

Heres the error i got:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/functions.php
>   on line 361 NUL

Comment: The message seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Welp i don't get it, i must be stupid or something @JonStirling

Comment: `$json` is an `array`. `json_decode` requires a `string`.

Comment: This is the only way i can think of to do what i want, is there another way to do the same thing? @JonStirling

Comment: Do what? `var_dump($json)` and have a look at what it's giving you (maybe add to the question too). It's not what you're thinking it is. Are you sure the SDK you're using isn't decoding the data for you?

Comment: Can you give me a look at `var_dump($json)` - I think the API Call returns a array and not a string.

Comment: @KoenHollander it returned an array indeed, i thought i had to decode it first because the original data is in json format.

Comment: If you want you can post it as an answer ill take it @KoenHollander

Comment: /me is sure he pointed that out 10 mins ago...

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `var_dump($json)`. The variable contains an array, not a JSON (json = string). I don't know SimplicateApi, but maybe the json you want is in the array returned by the makeApiCall method?